# Backup directory as zip files of 1gb under Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, backup, compression

I'm searching for a solution to take a big directory and make a multiarchive zip backup with each zipfile being 1gig. I've looked at zipsplit but appearently you can not actually split files, ie. one of the files in that directory is 5gig, so zipsplit can't handle it because it's bigger then the target size of the zipfile. I like to make zipfiles to make it easier for windows users to access the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not use zip but tar+gzip. What I do is

```
tar czf - /some/dir | split -b 1G
```

This will create files xaa xab etc.. (you can change the prefix. Check the man pages)

To restore simply `cat` the files together, i.e.

```
cat xaa xab ... | tar xzf -
```

It looks like you can do that with `zip` to, using a `-` for filename, something like (untested)

```
zip - /some/dir | split ...
```